# Set value to FontDialog in WPF

Tags: wpf, fonts, edit

I am working on WPF with text. Now I want to edit text using FontDialog but I cannot set current style of text to FontDialog so the style of text change everytime I call FontDialog. Can you guys help me?

This my code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.FontDialog fontDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FontDialog();
        if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textAnnotation.Font.Size = fontDialog.Font.Size;
            this.textAnnotation.Font.Name = fontDialog.Font.Name;
            this.textAnnotation.Font.Underline = fontDialog.Font.Underline;
            this.textAnnotation.Font.Strikeout = fontDialog.Font.Strikeout;
            this.textAnnotation.Font.Bold = fontDialog.Font.Bold;
            this.textAnnotation.Font.Italic = fontDialog.Font.Italic;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Font object in WPF is different than the Font object in Windows Forms which your FontDialog returns.

1. The Fontsize will not error but WPF Font Sizes are different that WinForms.
2. You will need to use a [FontFamilyConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamilyconverter.aspx) to set the Font Name.
3. The Underline and Strikeout are TextDecorations in WPF
4. For Font Style and Font Weight propertys you can use conditional logic to set the properties.

You would be better off using something that is native to Wpf since the Font objects are different. There is a [Sample Font Chooser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2006/11/01/sample-font-chooser.aspx) on the Wpf Text blog. I would recommend looking into it.

something like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.FontDialog fontDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FontDialog();
if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    FontFamilyConverter ffc = new FontFamilyConverter();

    this.textAnnotation.FontSize = fontDialog.Font.Size;
    this.textAnnotation.FontFamily =(FontFamily)ffc.ConvertFromString(fontDialog.Font.Name);

    if (fontDialog.Font.Bold)
        textAnnotation.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    else
        textAnnotation.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

    if (fontDialog.Font.Italic)
        textAnnotation.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
    else
        textAnnotation.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Hall... But I mean I want to set current style of text to FontDialog. For Example: I create new Annotation Text. I call Font Dialog to edit text and click OK after completing. Then I call Font Dialog again but it set default value. So how can I set style of text to FontDialog?

Comment: @user1276594 Maybe I am not understanding, but the code I gave you above **will** change the FontFamily, Size, FontWeight and FontStyle. The two font objects are very different and there is not an easy way to do a complete conversion. That is why I suggested you look at the Sample Font Chooser it is a native wpf font dialog.

Comment: @user1276594 - I think I understand what he is saying. He wants to be able to set the strikethrough, underline, etc BACK to the FontDialog the next time he calls it. So he can transfer the settings from the WPF text back to the FontDialog - I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @JuniperAsh.  I did understand what he was saying, that is why I suggested the Sample File Chooser which is a Wpf example. The two Fonts are different, and it is hard to get a corellation between certain aspects of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Font object passing your current style of text as parameter. This is how you can do it :

```
        var fontDialog = new FontDialog();
        fontDialog.Font = new Font(textInfo.FontFamily, textInfo.FontSize);

        if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var selectedFont = fontDialog.Font;
            textInfo.FontSize = selectedFont.Size;
            textInfo.FontFamily = selectedFont.FontFamily.Name;
            textInfo.FontWeight = selectedFont.Bold ? "Bold" : "Regular";
            textInfo.FontStyle = selectedFont.Italic ? "Italic" : "Normal";            
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work to instantiate a System.Drawing.Font in the FontDialog using System.Windows.Media.Font properties of FontFamily and FontSize